# How can I validate my file input name using regex?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I can't seem to figure out why my code below is not running correctly.  I am not sure if the issue is coming from the match function syntax or the regex.  Any help is appreciated.

```
$scope.fileSelected = function (file) {
    var valid = "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/";
    if (file.name.match(!valid)) {
        alert("File name contains invalid characters. (#, &, %, etc.)");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably the misplaced `!`. It should be `if (!file.name.match(valid))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

The problem is you are putting the exclamation mark in the wrong place. Try this:

```
if (!file.name.match(valid)){
```

**Explanation:**

The exclamation mark gives you the boolean opposite of a given value. That is: if something is "truthy" it gives you `false`, and if something is "falsy" it gives you `true`.

Here's more information about truthy/falsy, which is a very important concept in many programming languages: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Your variable `valid` is a RegEx object, and will always be truthy. Therefore, `!valid` will always be `false`.

The way you originally wrote your code is basically saying:

> If the file's name matches "false"

What you want to say is:

> If this statement is false: "the file's name matches this RegEx"